# $\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\|= \|x\|$ for every $\lambda\in [0,1]$, then x=y

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ a inner product space

if $\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\|= \|x\|$ for every $\lambda\in [0,1]$,  then x=y

I worked this problem but I don't find the proof... can you give me a suggestion?

Comment: Use triangle inequality which results in contradiction to the assumption of $x\neq y$.

Comment: I'm tried that, and I just could deduct this; $\|y\| \leq \|x\|$  @K.K.McDonald

Comment: You should add the work that you did into your post, or it might be closed.

Answer (score 3):

You only need the equality for $\lambda=0$ and some fixed $\lambda$ other than $0$ and $1$. From $\lambda=0$ we get $\|y\|=\|x\|$. And, for $0<\lambda<1$, you have
\begin{align}
\|x\|^2&=\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\|^2
=
\langle \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y,\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lambda^2\|x\|^2+(1-\lambda)^2\|y\|+2\lambda(1-\lambda)\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\lambda^2\|x\|^2+(1-\lambda)^2\|x\|+2\lambda(1-\lambda)\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\|x\|^2-2\lambda(1-\lambda)\|x\|+2\lambda(1-\lambda)\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y\rangle.
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\|x\|^2=\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y\rangle.
$$
This gives us
$$
\|x-y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-2\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y\rangle =2\|x\|^2-2\|x\|^2=0,
$$
So $y=x$.